# Problems with grid's lines view using matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, gridview, graph, grid

First of all, i'm sorry for my bad english.
When I try to insert grid in a graph created with `plt.subplots`, grid's lines don't appear if they are on axis number positions. This behaviour happens both for x-axis and for y-axis. I show my code:

```
pnt = listaPnt[i]
work = ax.flat[i]
im = work.imshow(lista[i], origin='lower', vmin=0, vmax=1, cmap=newcmp, extent=[0,mu_lim, 0,mu_lim])
work.plot(line, '-', color='grey', linewidth=0.8)
work.plot(line-line*0.10, '-', color='grey', linewidth=0.8)
work.plot(line+line*0.10, '-', color='grey', linewidth=0.8)
work.plot(line-line*0.25, '--', color='grey', linewidth=0.8)
work.plot(line+line*0.25, '--', color='grey', linewidth=0.8)
work.plot(pnt[:,1], pnt[:,0], '-', color='black', linewidth=1.5)
work.plot(pnt[:,1], pnt[:,0]-pnt[:,0]*0.25, '-', color='blue', linewidth=1.5)
work.plot(pnt[:,1], pnt[:,0]+pnt[:,0]*0.25, '-', color='blue', linewidth=1.5)
        
grid_x_ticks = np.arange(0, mu_lim, mu_lim/bins)
grid_y_ticks = np.arange(0, mu_lim, mu_lim/bins)

work.set_xticks(grid_x_ticks , minor=True
work.set_yticks(grid_y_ticks , minor=True)

work.grid(which='minor', alpha=0.1, linestyle='-', color='b')

work.set_ylabel('$\mu}$', fontsize='30')
work.set_xlabel('$\mu_{R}$', fontsize='30')
work.set_title('$z_s = '+str(zs)+'$'+stringa[i],

...
```

This processes are in a for cycle. The results is in figure. Can I resolve this problem?[Every square has counts, the scale of colors is on the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlJZ9.png)

Comment: `work.grid(which='both',...)` to get grid lines on *both* minor and major ticks?

Comment: Thank you, with this key word I resolved my problem!